# Vue assets image url auto changed

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I will get an image that I use in Vue project as url from another project. No problem on vue side when I call it like this :

```
    <v-img
      class="header__logo"
      lazy-src="@/assets/images/mail.jpg"
      src="@/assets/images/mail.jpg"
      alt="Logo"
    ></v-img>
```

When I look at the url from the browser, I see that the place marked in bold has been added and I see that this code changes every time we release.

http://localhost:8081/img/mail.**3d6d7034**.jpg

How can I set this to not change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is that hash in my asset file name?

**Assets** in a vue-cli / nuxt 2 project **are bundled using webpack** (more specifically the [asset-module](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/). That means they are included into a code chunk to reduce http requests and size.

> Read vue-cli documentation about [assets](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling).

While bundling, the **webpack module** also includes a hash into the emitted file name. That's why this part changes over every build.

**Solution**: If you require this image file to have a static name, you can include it into your **`public/` folder** instead.
It won't go through webpack, and its name will not be altered. The downside of this is that you have to use the absolute path of the file, it's not longer relative using `@/assets/...`.

> Read about the [public folder](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder).